# How to convert text to voice without use display and instead save file to mp3? (python)

Tags: python

How to convert text to voice without use display and instead save file to mp3? (python)

I want save my audio to file but i don't know what i can do this

full code - https://colab.research.google.com/github/d8oss/akeke/blob/main/DeepVoice.ipynb

but i want do this on my operation system.

(This is not the whole code)

```
    import torch

language = 'ru'
speaker = 'baya_16khz'
device = torch.device('cpu')
model, symbols, sample_rate, example_text, apply_tts = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                                                      model='silero_tts',
                                                                      language=language,
                                                                      speaker=speaker)
model = model.to(device)  # gpu or cpu

audio = apply_tts(texts=["Привет как дела"],
                  model=model,
                  sample_rate=sample_rate,
                  symbols=symbols,
                  device=device)

print(example_text)
display(Audio(audio[0], rate=sample_rate))
```

Another words-How i can do this script on my desktop https://colab.research.google.com/github/d8oss/akeke/blob/main/DeepVoice.ipynb

Comment: Welcome to SO :). I encourage you to read over [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your questions accordingly so the community can help you as best as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `torchaudio` for this:

```
import torchaudio
```

After getting audio from `apply_tts`, save the audio as MP3 using following code:

```
torchaudio.save(f'test_1.mp3',
                  audio[0].unsqueeze(0),
                  sample_rate=16000)
```

[Source](https://habr.com/ru/post/549482/#comment_22877508)

Comment: I have this error - ValueError: Unsupported format: mp3

Then i changed code mp3 to wav and done!

Thanks dude you save my nervous!!!

Comment: Looks like saving MP3 is not supported in Windows by torchaudio yet.